# Aplicação retorna null ao instanciar componente customizado

Tags: android, android-layout, customelements

Boa noite.

Preciso fazer com que um componente `AutoCompleteTextView` busque as informações diretamente do servidor e para isso estou seguindo o seguinte artigo:

http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

Quando vou executar a aplicação retorna erro nessa parte do XML falando que a classe não foi encontrada sendo que o caminho do arquivo `.java` esta correto:

```
<br.com.aplicacao.components.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/et_book_title"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_auto_complete"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"/>
```

Método `onCreate` da Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_register_emergency_service);
    this.edtDescription = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edtDescription);
    this.edtCellphoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCellphoneNumber);
}
```

LOG:

> 09-13 20:45:58.329: E/AndroidRuntime(29071): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "br.com.aplicacao.components.DelayAutoCompleteTextView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.aplicacao-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/br.com.aplicacao-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Qual seria a solução ou existe outra maneira para informar a classe do componente?

**EDIT**

Corrigi colocando `<components.DelayAutoCompleteTextView />`, porém agora no `onCreate` ao instanciar a variável do componente sempre esta retornando null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, segue para quem tiver o mesmo problema quanto a instanciação nula:

O segundo problema estava no método `onCreate` do componente, onde era preciso passar dois parametros no super, e não apenas um que seria o `Context`, quem precisar fazer o mesmo não se esqueça de declarar da seguinte maneira:

```
public DelayAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

E não desta maneira como estava fazendo anteriormente:

```
public DelayAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```